# Zend Form ViewScript getting rid of dt and dd tag?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form build with zend using a viewscript. I thought that by using a viewscript I'd get all the dd and dt eliminated and be able to use my own html tags on the form of the form script file (patientScriptForm.phtml)?

How do I use only the div tags in my form script file and not auto-generated dt and dd tags? Thanks!!

I have a very basic form with code below:

```
$age = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('age'); $age->setLabel('age');

$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit'); $submit->setValue($submit);

$this->addElement($age)->addElement($submit); 

$this->setDecorators(array ( array ('ViewScript',    array('viewScript' => 'patientScriptForm.phtml'))));
```

Below is my viewscript patientScriptForm.phtml

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->escape($this->element->getAction()) ?>" method="<?php echo $this->escape($this->element->getMethod()) ?>"> 
<div> 
<?php echo $this->element->age ?>
</div> 
<div>
<?php echo $this->element->submit ?>
</div> 
</form>
```

Below is the browser output:

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
<div> 
<dt id="age-label">
<label for="age" class="optional">age</label>
</dt> 
<dd id="age-element"> 
<input type="text" name="age" id="age" value="" />
</dd>
</div> 
<div>
<dt id="submit-label"> 
</dt>
<dd id="submit-element"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</dd>
</div> 
</form>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838074/how-to-remove-dd-and-dt-html-elements-when-rendering-a-form-element-in-zf.

Comment: +1 to Cymen. Specifically, the 'HtmlTag' decorator is adding the dt and dd tags. You can either customise this decorator to use different tags, or remove it altogether.

Comment: Hi Cymen, how do I go about removing it all together with 'HtmlTag'? I've experimented with HtmlTag decorator a bit with unsuccessful results..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that whilst using the `ViewScript` decorator for the form works for the form element itself, your elements each have their own default decorator scheme.

A simple solution in your view script could be

```
<?php echo $this->element->age->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper')) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I put this is on my view script file and got this error:
    Warning: No view script registered with ViewScript decorator in /Users/c33/zend-dev/library/Zend/Form/Element.php on line 2041

Comment: Thanks!! wow I can't believe how long it took me to find this answer. I had been looking around the net for two days straight. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

If your form has too many elements that appending

```
->setDecorators(array("ViewHelper"))
```

to the end of each echo statement in your view script doesn't seem so compelling, you can also do the following, which has the same effect as doing the above call for every single element in your form:

```
class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form {
   public function init() {
     // ...

     $this->setElementDecorators(
        array(
           "ViewHelper",
           "Errors"
        )
     );
   }
}
```